# Offline web app for distribution in pendrives (Windows only)?

Tags: html, windows, web-applications, offline

We are trying to distribute a basic HTML file with some links to a PDF document in a USB drive for advertising purposes. The idea is that an autorun opens up this HTML in the default browser. However, this might not be a good idea since it would look very amateur-ish and we will have to rely on the default browser's technology (which unfortunately has a good chance on being IE6/7!)

We've explored a few alternatives, but we can't find one that really fits what we are trying to achieve:

1. **[Mozilla Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/)**
   Altough it seems like it's designed with offline web apps in mind, the executable creates files in the user's AppData directory and it's hard to configure the default paths. Also, Firefox doesn't have a default PDF viewer, so we will have to depend on the user's default PDF viewer (which might be Adobe Reader)
2. **[Mozilla Chromeless](https://github.com/mozilla/chromeless)**
   Since Prism is inactive, the idea is still developing with Chromeless, which allows the developer to create the browser interface with basic HTML/JS/CSS. The main issue here is that somehow the build isn't loading HTML, all that's showing is a [gray iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1IMu.png). I'm not sure if it's just me, because there's nothing on the issues page.
3. **Portable App**
   We could throw in the portable version of Firefox or Chrome and customize the XUL for Firefox or [open Chrome in app mode](https://superuser.com/questions/33548/how-to-start-chrome-in-application-mode).

Firefox's advantage is that it kind of supports relative paths (`resource://`), but it doesn't have a built-in PDF viewer. Chrome has a very good and lightweight PDF viewer and the built-in app mode is a very useful feature for us, but I can't find how to open a local path without the usual absolute path (`file:///C:/`) since we don't know what's the drive's letter.

Has anyone figure out how to handle this kind of issues? Thanks.

Comment: Mozilla are working on a [client-side javascript native PDF renderer](http://blog.mozilla.com/cjones/2011/07/03/pdf-js-first-milestone/) which may help you if you go down the prism route.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked three years ago, but it's unanswered, listed high in Google, and I stumbled over the exact same problem and can imagine that many others that seek to ship portable web apps that can be run locally and with a minimum of dependencies will encounter this issue, too.

The solution I am now going with is the node-webkit.

You can treat it like a portable version of chrome, however it excepts a relative path to your app's entry point, is about 40 MB smaller, and much more customizable than the --app mode of chrome (which isn't customizable at all if I remember correctly).

Github & Download:
https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit#downloads

An extensive guide:
http://thejackalofjavascript.com/getting-started-with-node-webkit-apps/

My usage suggestion for Windows:

1. First create an app package as explained in the guide linked above
2. For the node-wekit to load with your app, you need to start it like this:

   nw.exe app.package

Where nw.exe is in the root of the zipped folder you downloaded and app.package is a zip file (can have any name) that contains your app data and package.json.

To do this silently, you can use a BAT file containing the (amended) call above and a VBS file containing something like this:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "cmd /c launchNW.bat", 0, true
```

launchNW.bat being the name of your BAT file. Now run the VBS file; a window containing your web app should pop up without the command window appearing with it.

3. Finish reading the linked guide to learn more about customization options to do things like hiding the browser UI etc.